# ModuleNotFoundError when executing Python program from bash script

Tags: bash, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, boto3

I have a script which monitors a directory using `inotify-tools`. When a new file is added to the directory, the script calls a python program and passes the path and fill name as arguments.

It all works fine, except that I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`... the module in question is boto3 (for AWS S3).

The python script works fine in Pycharms, so I really do not know what is causing the error.

Monitor script:

```
source=$1
pythonscriptlocation=$2

inotifywait -m $source -e create -e moved_to |
while read path action file; do
    python $pythonscriptlocation $path $file
done
```

Python script example:

```
import argparse
import boto3

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser();
parser.add_argument("source_path");
parser.add_argument("filename");
args = parser.parse_args();
print(args.source_path);
print(args.filename);
```

**Update - Solution**

It turned out that `ANACONDA` had added an environment variable to the bottom of my `.bashrc` file... as a result, it screwed up my `PATH`. Deleted the line and then 1 more problem: in the monitor script, I was calling `python`, but should have been calling `python3`.

Comment: Just wanted to see if things looked fine from the `bash` script side, did you try printing the values to see if they are fine, also do double quote your arguments, `python "$pythonscriptlocation" "$path" "$file"`

Comment: @Inian Thanks, but I have managed to figure out what the problem was...

Comment: You should always use isolated python development environment such as `virtualenv` or `conda` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you launching this script? I'd guess that the user environment you're running in is different from the interactive environment in some way.  The most likely cause is that you're setting the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable differently between these two environments -- try printing that out before running your Python code and seeing if it differs.

Another possibility is that you've got your path set differently in your two environments, and you're not even running the same Python version. Check your **PATH** environment variable and see if these are the same.

One reason these could be different is if your interactive environment, where the script works, is grabbing these or other configurations from your .profile file. The **.profile** is only read by login shells, not other shells.  Putting these in your **.bashrc** rather than **.profile** might make a difference.

(It should go without saying that if you're running as a different user in these two contexts, that the relevant environment variables need to be present in both users' configurations.)

Comment: I discovered that Anaconda (which I had installed previously) added a line to `.bashrc` which messed up my PATH. Thank you!

Comment: I also found out that I must call `python3` rather than `python`... so bloody fiddly! One problem after the next! #rantover.