# How to use boto3.dynamodb.condition import with Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, boto3

I'm working through [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html) guide on dynamodb. For querying and scanning, When I try to run the conditions import command I get an error of 'ImportError: No module named 'boto3.dynamodb.condition''.

```
     from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
```

I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.5 environment and executing the code in a Jupyter notebook on Windows. Boto3 was successfully installed through Anaconda and my AWS keys are working. I had no issues in importing boto3, creating a table, putting, and getting items.

All other posts I've seen on issues with boto3 seem to relate to not leveraging their [IAM account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464278/where-do-i-run-this-aws-rekognition-code-and-do-i-need-to-install-anything-else) which is working in my notebook or [path variable issue] ([ModuleNotFoundError when executing Python program from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563446/modulenotfounderror-when-executing-python-program-from-bash-script)) which doesn't seem to apply.

```
   import boto3
   dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-1')

   from boto3.dynamodb.condition import Key, Attr

   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-10-ba2b4a731ee7> in <module>()
   ----> 1 from boto3.dynamodb.condition import Key, Attr

   ImportError: No module named 'boto3.dynamodb.condition'
```

Is it possible to use the full dynamodb functionality with anaconda and jupyter notebooks? Is there a better way to set up the environment to use boto3 dynamodb functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is just a small typo in your import!

As you say in your post, the guide says:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
```

but your code has the line:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.condition import Key, Attr
```

Note the missing `s` on `condition`. I was able to run your code in an Anaconda with Python 3.5 environment after fixing the import statement.